# Update currently fetched array PHP on a MYSQL table without a primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, key, fetch

I have a MySQl table with large number of columns without a primary key. It is been imported via an external csv file.

I have a php code which fetches cell values from the current row modifies them and have to replace/update the current row itself. I fetch the results simply by iterating through individual rows.. however as there is no primary key.. i am unable to modify the cell value.

However, since there is no primary key, but php is fetching the current row, i just want to update the current row being fetched. How can we grab the current row?

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you have a table with a large number of rows, with no primary key?

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this. Keeping in mind that you also have a large number of rows I would advice you to create a new column and make it primary.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The table is created according to csv fields. If i would had a primary, then there wouldn't had been any issue. I want to update the currently fetched row.

Comment: What are you trying to update?  Is it an operation that could be done to all rows in one operation?

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing this from a csv file, I would recommend you to add a new "ID" column to the csv file.  Set each value in that column to be a unique number (most likely the row number).  Then, when you import it into mysql, you'll have a unique row identifier to work with.

Comment: Thank you Harry for your reply. I cannot modify the csv as i have to export it the same way after making the alterations. I just want to update the currently fetched row.

Comment: Are the rows unique in any other way?  For example, is it possible for 2 rows to be exactly the same, or is every row different?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using phpmyadmin i suggest you create an "ID" field to make your task easier